# Matplotlib and mpi4py: Tclerror: no display name and no $DISPLAY

Tags: python, matplotlib, yt

I post here a runnable example of a previous Python script, following the suggestion of ngoldbaum. At the end I would like to have root to execute a plot (from package scitools, which invokes matplotlib), but it runs into error and does not produce any output.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import sys
import numpy as np
import yt
from scitools.all import *
from scitools.std import *
from matplotlib import rc
from mpi4py import MPI

yt.enable_parallelism()


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
nprocs = comm.Get_size()

print "rank, nprocs", rank, nprocs

# 
out_tmax = []
out_zmax = []
n_el = np.zeros(nprocs, dtype=int)

xmin = 0.
xmax = 2.2
deltax = (xmax - xmin)/nprocs

xmin_loc = xmin + rank*deltax
xmax_loc = xmin_loc + deltax

n_el[rank] = 10*(1 + rank)
if rank == 0:
    out_tmax = np.linspace(xmin_loc,xmax_loc,n_el[rank])
    out_zmax = sin(out_tmax)
    print "ok", out_tmax, out_zmax

# Plot
if yt.is_root():
#if rank == 0:
    rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Times']})
## for Palatino and other serif fonts use:
#    rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Palatino']})
    rc('text', usetex=True)
    rc('legend',fontsize=12)
    rc('axes',labelsize=14, titlesize=18)
    rc('xtick', labelsize=14)
    rc('ytick', labelsize=14)
    plot(out_tmax, out_zmax, 'b', fontname='Times new Roman', xlabel=(r'Time (Myr)'), ylabel=(r'\mathrm{z_{HS}}'), hardcopy='fig1.png')
```

It looks like the root process did not inherit the "use: Agg" choice made at the beginning (I do not get any *png output as specified in plot(). I submit it to the PBS batch system using s cript:

```
#!/bin/bash
## Name of the job
#PBS -N test_mpi4py_matlib

#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=4:mpiprocs=4:mem=24gb
#PBS -l place=scatter

#PBS -e test_gatherv_print.err
#PBS -o test_gatherv_print.out
#PBS -l walltime=00:20:00
....
mpirun python2.7 test_gatherv_print.py
```

The first two lines of this script should prevent plot (based on matplotlib) to look for the DISPLAY environment variable.

This script fails with the following error:

```
  File "test_gatherv_print.py", line 49, in <module>
    plot(out_tmax, out_zmax, 'b', fontname='Times new Roman', xlabel=(r'Time (Myr)'), ylabel=(r'\mathrm{z_{H
S}}'), hardcopy='fig1.png')
  File "/home/van/software/python/scitools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scitools/easyviz/common.py", line 313
9, in plot
    self.setp(**kwargs)
  File "/home/van/software/python/scitools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scitools/easyviz/common.py", line 194
1, in setp
    self.hardcopy(kwargs['hardcopy'])
  File "/home/van/software/python/scitools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scitools/easyviz/matplotlib_.py", lin
e 1065, in hardcopy
    self._replot()
  File "/home/van/software/python/scitools/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scitools/easyviz/matplotlib_.py", lin
e 944, in _replot
    self._g.figure(self.getp('curfig'))
  File "/opt/Python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 533, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/opt/Python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 161, in new_figure_
manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "/opt/Python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 1046, in new
_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk(className="matplotlib")
  File "/opt/Python-2.7.9/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1810, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
P000 yt : [ERROR    ] 2020-05-13 16:28:32,964 TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
P000 yt : [ERROR    ] 2020-05-13 16:28:32,965 Error occured on rank 0.
```

although I specified the 'Agg' output in matplotlib.use() above.

Comment: Can you make a minimal runnable example that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I hope I understand what you mean by "minimal runnable example"...The script basically reads a series of FLASH outputs, Then I invoke yt (a Python package data analysis package) which shares the job among Np processes (using the .piter() method to parallelize this segment) , the outputs arrays are sent back to root which sequentially collects them into 2 np arrays (tmax and zmax), and finally I issue plot(tmax, zmax,...) as seen above to make a plot. Is this what you are asking? Have I understood correctly?

Comment: I edited my question above to include the complete script.

Comment: This seems like an interaction between matplotlib and mpi4py, yet you’re importing a large number of modules besides those, particularly yt. You’re also using data that only you have.

Comment: A minimal example needs to be runnable on a machine that’s not yours, for one. It should also do as little extranenous work as possible.

Comment: I have substituted the original script with a runnable example, much shorter , simpler and self-contained, which runs into the same error. It seems that root does not inherit the matplotlib settings (?).

Comment: What is scitools? Do you still get the error if you make a plot manually without using scitools?

Comment: Note that matplotlib is getting called by scitools in your traceback, I have no idea what scitools is doing to set up the plot, but maybe it's doing it in a way that ignores the backend setting you wanted.

Comment: Maybe you just need to set Agg as your default backend in your matplotlibrc?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions. I had already tried all what you suggest: 1) matplotlibrc was configured (backend: Agg) both in the local directory and from under .config; 2) used matplotlib commands instead of the "plot" from scitools. Concerning the latter, it is a package of utilities developed by P. Langtangen; in particular I used here the easyviz subpackage (see: https://hplgit.github.io/scitools/doc/api/html/easyviz.html). However even when I DO NOT use scitools.easyviz and instead use directly matplotlib I am unable to produce a .png output from within a MPI spawned root process. I substituted the following lines at the end:

```
...
    plt.plot(out_tmax, out_zmax)
    plt.savefig('fig1.png')
```

and now I get the following error:

```
P000 yt : [ERROR    ] 2020-05-14 10:32:14,200 OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'latex'
P000 yt : [ERROR    ] 2020-05-14 10:32:14,200 Error occured on rank 0.
```

Note that when I run interactively the script it correctly produces the fig1.png output.
As you may see the problem has now shifted: root does not read some environment variables. Note that I submit the job to PBS batch system. The last script was like that:

```
#!/bin/tcsh
## Name of the job
#PBS -N test_mpi4py_matlib

## Number of nodes (in this case I require 8 nodes with 1 CPU each)
## The total number of nodes passed to mpirun will be nodes*ppn 
##PBS -l nodes=5:ppn=16
##PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=8
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=4:mpiprocs=4:mem=24gb
#PBS -l place=scatter
#PBS -V 
# inherits all environment variables, including DISPLAY

#! Name of output files for std output and error;
#! if non specified defaults are <job-name>.o<job number> and <job-name>.e<job-number>
#
#PBS -e test_gatherv_print.err
#PBS -o test_gatherv_print.out
#PBS -l walltime=00:20:00
##PBS -q high


#comandi
#printenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH
printenv DISPLAY

cd /home/van/projects/jet_ism/turbulence/python

date
#echo 'Hello world'
/opt/openmpi_icc/bin/mpirun python2.7 test_gatherv_print.py
```

Here I use tcsh, BUT before I used also ksh.

Comment: Probably LaTeX isn’t installed on the compute nodes.